# Force aspect ratio of streaming video?

Tags: video, aspect-ratio

Many streaming videos are in the wrong aspect ratio. Almost all discussion of this I ever find deals with how to download and correct the videos, or how to make sure your videos are correct if you're uploading them. I'm specifically asking for a way to control the aspect ratio of streaming videos.

For YouTube, I have a Greasemonkey script installed that does exactly this. But... that's only for YouTube. I want something that works on (hopefully) any Flash-based streaming video, including in fullscreen mode.

Linux Mint 12 KDE, Firefox 12.0, Flash 11.0.1.152.

Answer (score 2):

I made a bookmarklet that lets you rescale all html5 video, either by a pair of explicit scale factors or to adjust it to a specific aspect ratio:  http://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2018/08/adjust-aspect-ratio-of-online-videos.html